# How to specify a color theme specifically for Latex editing (the buffers with .tex files)?

Tags: latex, themes, colors, bibtex

I am using `Emacs` and there are various 'themes', eg. [link to examples](https://emacsthemes.com/index/12.html), but they do not appear to be dedicated to Latex. Some have modes for Latex, but I am wondering if there are theme files that can be loaded specifically when using Latex (dedicated themes), and if this exists how would the init.el file be set to use the appropriate theme file?

I have tried to use the lines in my `init.el`

```
(require 'color-theme-buffer-local)
 (add-hook 'latex-mode 
     (lambda nil (color-theme-buffer-local 'color-theme-empty-void (current-buffer))))
```

This color-theme (color-theme-empty-void), was taken from [link to theme .el file](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/color-theme-empty-void.el). Is it maybe not customary to have a specific color theme for Latex?

Comment: Pretty much, nobody except for me, uses the builtin latex-mode.  Everyone, and their relatives, use AUCTeX which is so complicated, I gave up years ago messing with.  Fonts can be made buffer-local with the `face-remapping-alist` -- so you would be looking for theme threads dealing with that and/or the front-end for that variable; i.e., `face-remap-add-relative`.  I have actually modified the built-in latex-mode and customized my own version based thereon.   Some time ago there was an advancement from regular old color-themes, to new version of themes, and I lost interest in keeping up ...

Comment: @lawlist, I was hoping that there is a simple import of the color theme that can be designated to the buffer and avoid the AUCTEX learning curve and added complexity.

Comment: To increase your Google search, you might want to type in Emacs:  `M-x find-library RET tex-mode RET` and search for the word `font-lock` and see which *existing* faces are used; and, also search for `defface` to see what new faces are defined.  Then, Google search for keywords like:  emacs latex-mode theme font-lock-function-name-face and so on to see what theme libraries may exist.  I would imagine 99.9 percent will be relating to `AUCTeX`, but perhaps .1 percent will be relating to the built-in tex-mode.  It might be easier just to see what faces are used and define your own customization.